# How to create instance of already loaded class by other application in same JVM?

Tags: java, reflection

I have created two small java applications in Netbeans IDE, Say

**App1** have class **First** as follow

```
public class First{

  public static void main(String... str){
    First f = new First();
    System.out.print(f.getValue());
  }

  public int getValue(){
    return 10;
  }
}
```

And **App2** have class **Second** as follow

```
public class Second {
  public static void main(String... str){
    try{
      Class myClass = Class.forName("App1.First");
      Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("getValue",new Class[] {});
      Object result = m.invoke(myClass,null);
      System.out.println(result);
    }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I have Run App1.First in Netbeans and after that i have run App2.Second in Netbeans.

> **OUTPUT:**  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App1.First

Code above is not working. **I want to Access getValue method in App1.First from App2.second.**

> I want to know whether we can create instance of class from other application and execute its methods on it in Java? If yes, then How?
>   Consider **SecurityManager** is not running.**Please let me know where i have done mistake in code OR understanding concept.**

**Your response will be greatly appreciated.**

> **Thanks for all the responses. If Netbeans runs each app in different JVM then May i know How we can run an Application in JVM in which other application is already running?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

Each application has its own JVM, with its own class path, loaded classes, etc. You can't (within pure Java) access one JVM's classes directly from another class.

What you'd need to do is to put App1's classes on the classpath for App2 -- there are tools such as [maven](http://maven.apache.org) that help you set these dependencies up. If you do that, both JVMs will have a separate copy of each class; it's up to you to make sure that both copies are identical (for instance, by making sure you redeploy App2 every time you redeploy App1). You'll also need to set up some way for the JVMs to communicate to each other: set up a socket or some similar approach, with a serialization format (serialized classes, [protobufs](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), etc) that both agree on.

Comment: You mean Netbeans run each app in Different JVM? Let consider is the Same JVM.Is your answer will be same i.e. we cannot without using other tools

Comment: I'm not familiar with Netbeans specifically, but yes, most IDEs create a separate JVM for each run of each application. Otherwise they'd need some really careful classoader trickery, to make sure that each application isn't running the wrong classes. You don't _have_ to use other tools -- you could manually create the jars with the proper dependencies. It's just easier with tools that do this for you.

Comment: So this is type of hack in to other app and JAVA will not allow it any way? My intention was hack into other application.u think it may be silly thing i am doing but it only for knowledge.

Comment: Correct, this will not let you hack into a Java process running in a separate JVM. That would be one hell of a security hole, if it were that easy!

Comment: (Also, it's "Java," not "JAVA." It's not an acronym. You may see "JAVA" out there a lot, but it's wrong. :) )

Answer (score 1):

First.
When you start 2 different programm, you have 2 differenc instances of JVM. Each JVM not know nothing about another.

Second.
Exception is occurs when class is not contained in classpath. You must add dependencies `App1` for project `App2` i.e. put classes from `App1` to classpath `App2`.

Comment: sorry I didnt get what you want to say. But there is no such a dependency.It is just small program.

Answer (score 1):

If App1 and App2 are two different application/ projects, App2 will not see APP1's classes unless included in classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Each app when you run using java command, it starts in different JVM. so you cannot load class using this way in the same JVM